# Ошибка в регулярном выражении при проверке номера телефона

Tags: php

```
    $phone = "";
if(isset($_POST['telephone'])) {
    $phone = $_POST['telephone'];
    if(mb_strlen($phone) >= 1) {
        if(!preg_match($phone, '/^\d[\d\(\)\ -]{4,14}\d$/')) {
            $validationError = true;
            $errors[] = 'Некорректный номер телефона.';
        }
    }
} else {
    $validationError = true;
    $errors[] = 'Невозможно найти номер телефона. Введите данные заново.';
}
```

В результате выполнение скрипта в массиве errors появляется значение 'Невозможно найти номер телефона. Введите данные заново.'

Как решить эту проблему? Или посоветуете другое регулярное выражение?

Comment: Ну так проблема не в регулярном выражение, а в том, что `$_POST['telephone']` не существует. Ну и в дополнении. Проверять `mb_strlen` не нужно, у вас в регулярном выражении заложена длина. `$validationError` не нужен, достаточно проверить `count(errors)`

Comment: @ArchDemon, почему переменной $_POST['telephone'] не существует? Я же сделал проверку isset. Объясните, пожалуйста, подробнее.

Comment: Не существует, потому что твой код выполняет else-ветку, а она выполняется если isset равен false.

Comment: @u_mulder, вы же понимаете, что я запрос выполняю через форму. При проверке isset переменная $_POST['telephone'] существует, даже если переменная пустая. Следовательно, код должен выполняться по true-ветке. Разве я неправильно рассуждаю.

Comment: Рассуждения правильные, но твой код  говорит о том что `$_POST['telephone']` __не установлен__. Для проверки можно сделать `print_r($_POST)` и посмотреть что там есть.